# InvalidAlgorithmParameterException issue in Sqoop with ssl enabled for MS SQLdatabase

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, cloudera, sqoop, cloudera-cdh

I'm running Sqoop commands to import data from MS SQL with SSL enabled .
I have created the keystore and added the certificates to the keystore. I'm using Sqoop version 1.4.6-cdh5.11.2

Below is my Sqoop command :

```
sqoop import -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
--driver "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
--connect "jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxxx:1433;databaseName=xxx-example;encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;hostNameInCertificate=xxxxxx.xxxx.net;trustStore=/home/user1/trust.jks;trustStorePassword=xxxx" 
--username User1 
--password 'xxxxx' 
--null-string '\\N' 
--null-non-string '\\N' -delete-target-dir 
--target-dir "/home/john/PROGRAMS" 
--table programs 
--fields-terminated-by "\001" 
--hive-drop-import-delims 
--split-by 'ID' 
--outdir 'temp/john/tables' 
--bindir '/usr/john/PROGRAMS' -m 1
```

I've set the encryptions as true , TrustServerCertificate as false , trustStore= and trustStorePassword as the keystore password.

```
encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False
```

Below is the error that i get while running the sqoop command :

```
18/01/22 10:12:10 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1516292804343_13212_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty". 
 at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setDbConf(DBInputFormat.java:170)
 at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:161)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:755)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
 at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1920)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty".
 at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:223)
 at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setDbConf(DBInputFormat.java:168)
 ... 10 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty". 
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1667)
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1668)
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1323)
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
 at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getConnection(DBConfiguration.java:302)
 at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:216)
 ... 11 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
 at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1906)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1889)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1410)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1618)
```

How can i solve this issue ?

I've tried adding -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore= , but it didn't work.

Comment: Try removing the SSL part from the sqoop command, you don't need to mention the SSL certificates it works on TCP.

Comment: @rob The whole purpose of this is to bring in SSL , avoid a middle man attack and walk the certificate chain to validate trust. I've set encrypt=true ,TrustServerCertificate=false.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft doc says, For SSL to work at all, it is absolutely necessary to have the JSSE providers configured correctly for the JRE you are using.  There are two steps to this:

> 1)      Look at the java.security file in your JRE installation
>   (typically found in the jre\lib\security directory).  The installed
>   security providers are listed in that file as security.provider.x=…
>   where ‘x’ is the priority used.  For Sun JRE installations, the first
>   priority provider should be Sun’s.  E.g.: you should have the line
>   “security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun” in that file.  For
>   other JRE's, please refer to the JRE's documentation regarding their
>   default provider name.  We recommend when using the IBM JRE to specify
>   the "com.ibm.jsse.IBMJSSEProvider" as the first security provider to
>   use.
>
> 2)      Next, make sure that the classpath points to the correct JAR
>   files (in the jre\lib directory) for use with those providers.  For
>   Sun, the classpath should include jsse.jar.  For IBM,  should include
>   ibmjsse.jar.

Please refer [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jdbcteam/2008/09/09/the-driver-could-not-establish-a-secure-connection-to-sql-server-by-using-secure-sockets-layer-ssl-encryption/) Microsoft doc that is explained by the same error you are getting (“The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error)

Looks like you have to pass the below java parameters in the sqoop job

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\MyCertificates\storeName  
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=storePassword
```